# Angular-ui jQuery Passthrough Not Working

Tags: angularjs

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but for some reason I can not get AngularJS UI's jquery passthrough to work correctly.

I think I have the module setup correctly (copied the example from the angular-ui site).

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/huYQ6/2/

Comment: mouseover should say 'Peasy', right?  Works for me on Chrome

Comment: Yea. Are you just seeing the system yellow background tooltip?  I'm in chrome also and not seeing the toolip like in the example. http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-jq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to import jQuery before angular to make it use jQuery for angular.element (because angular-ui use angular.element to look for jQuery.fn.yourFunction), here's a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/huYQ6/6/

Comment: It does actually work even if you import app.ui in which case the config will also be picked up: http://jsfiddle.net/huYQ6/7/

Comment: Ho OK actually I didn't see you were actually splitting modules in your own app.

Comment: Well it's not my app :) but it's great how Angular can resolve the dependency of the sub module so you don't have to list it again in the app's dependency list

Comment: sorry it was time to go to bed for me I guess :)

Comment: latest jquery not working so updated fiddle to be working : http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/huYQ6/21/

Comment: Are you sure it's fixed? I just see the native tooltip (title attribute)